# CSS/ Query: Putting a clickable icon between the th and td of a table, without using a second table

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, datatables

I have a standard table that looks like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>column1</th>
            <th>column2</th>
            <th>column3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>data1</td>
            <td>data2</td>
            <td>data3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data1</td>
            <td>data2</td>
            <td>data3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data1</td>
            <td>data2</td>
            <td>data3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to add an overlapping clickable icon that would be sitting just in between each th and the td directly below it.

Here is a visual:

[image]

This overlapping icons/divs/cells shouldn't be inside their corresponding th or td below as they would have their own jQuery event (only triggered by the icons, not by the th's or td's they overlap).
So, basically, clicking on the th will sort the data, clicking on a td would allow you to edit the data and clicking on the intermediate icon, would allow you to stretch the column to its full size.

These icons should be fully part of the table and their corresponding table column as they should react the same way their column does (move, stretch, drag, hide, etc...)

To overcome this, I had to create another invisible table + thead + th's on top of the original table, with the icons in them and make the second table move and react exactly as the first one. But it's tedious as hell and just makes the script unnecessarily complicated.
I have to synchronize the two tables for each and every event that acts on the whole. It's ok but the code is a real mess.

Is there a relatively simple **ONE TABLE** solution to my problem? HTML, CSS or jQuery, I don't care as long as it works in a straightforward way so that I can only concentrate on the table and expect the icon to behave accordingly.

I'm not asking about the event, just how to have an icon tied to the table column, between each th and the first below it.

Thanks.

PS: The ideal would be to have a 0px high intermediate cell below each th (in other words, a whole new tr), dedicated to these icons but the icon should have a z-index bigger than its container cell so that the icon should visually overlap the upper th and the lower td (see picture above). Moreover, the whole icon should remain clickable, beyond its container's area. But I doubt I can have an icon with a z-index that is bigger than its container, can I?

Comment: Are these horizontal scrolling buttons supposed to be placed under header row only, as it is displayed at your screenshot?

Comment: Yes, they will always be "between" the thead and tbody (at least, visually). Nowhere else. Basically, these icons are for stretching their corresponding column and will always be placed there (provided their column is eligible for stretching, of course).

Comment: You don't need to put extra overlapping table, if you use `fixedColumn` option along with `scrollX`. FixedColumn extension already creates one overlapping table, you may put your scrolling buttons over there, along with great deal of CSS, though: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/

Comment: Thanks. But why fixedColumn  and scrollX should be involved as I don’t have  fixed columns and I don’t scroll through the table, just stretch columns? My table is responsive and adapt it self to the screen, it never needs to be scrolled. Besides, fixedColumn does exactly what I want to avoid: add another virtual table that needs to be taken care of each time you act on the original table. I already have that (see original message). For what I’m asking, I don’t expect a datatable  proprietary solution, Just a standard html/css/jquery one. Thanks!

Comment: Then, I don't really get, what those buttons are supposed to do?

Comment: Stretch (not scroll) the content of a column when it is truncated. But that I do. The event is already taken care of. All I need is to have those stretch icons to appear where they appear within a table (between the th and the td) without using a second table. My question is about the HTML/CSS, Not about a dataTable feature.

Comment: Then, why don't you simply append the child, encompassing your button to each `column().header()` within `initComplete` option callback and adjust with CSS buttons style and position. Thus, you'll keep the link to DataTable when you'll need to interact with its columns (width, content, whatever)?

Comment: That's the idea, exactly. But how to attach an icon (thus probably a div) to something that is not a TH or a TD within a table (it has to be between those, not inside one of those, as you can see in the picture)? That's the core of the problem.
If I put the icon inside the th for instance, it will be INSIDE it, so it won't overlap on the td below. Visually, it has to be between the th and td and that's the tricky part I can't overcome without a second table as a workaround. I hope it eventually makes sense. It's hard to explain.

Comment: You definitely need to make wrapping `<div>` for those buttons to be a child of `<th>` nodes. By this, you'll be able to identify corresponding table column `.onclick()` by using `.closest('th')`. Your major problem let that buttons wrapping `<div>` appear as if between the rows is solved by CSS, using `position: relative` and `top: 10px`, for instance. CSS will also help you with applying background images to your buttons.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll see what I can do with css.

Comment: This web site is weird at times.  One person downvoted without leaving any comment and when I edit my post to politely ask why, so that I can learn, another one deletes my legitimate question without commenting why neither . It is ethically questionable because, for all I know, it could very well be the same person. That is pure censorship. It’s very cold in here.

Comment: That's not me both of the times, if that's what you mean. However, I may guess, you're downvoted for not showing your own efforts to solve your problem. But I agree with you, that's not very polite to do so without explaining the reason, though.

Comment: Had similar problem as that posed... FWIW, solved my problem by placing fontawesome icon in with the table cell value and then using CSS `margin-top:-15px` and `margin-left:-20px` applied to the icon to move it between rows.